# NSMutableArray is not being saved

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I'm doing this :

```
  for(int k=0;k<[dataWord count];k++)
     {
         NSNumber *num=[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] ;
         [preDataWord insertObject:num atIndex:k ];
     }
```

when `preDataWord` is allocated before .

later when I'm trying to use this array I get all zero's.
Why is that? Do i have to retain it? How?

**EDIT :**
on my init i have  `preDataWord=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`
where `preDataWord` is declared in the class interface .
this class is running in another thread(audio unit) .
when i log the array right after the for loop, i can see its full and just fine.
later when another function trying to use it, she sees 0....

Comment: are you sure that `preDataWord` is allocated? put an NSLog before the `insertObject` statement to check it's not nil...

Comment: i did. after i fill the array i can see that it has all 2's. but after a while he some how loses all of its values .

Comment: Are you using ARC?  My guess is that `preDataWord` is not `strong`.

Comment: (Remember that any method call on a `nil` pointer produces a zero/nil result.)

Comment: Instead of doing `insertObject` you can use `addObject`, that won't need `index` and all.

Comment: 1 - as already written, check you are initializing preDataWord correctly. 2- what do you mean by "using later"? If preDataWord is a local variable, it is valid only in the same method where is declared. If you want to use it in another method, you must pass it or use an instance variable

Comment: Yep, it's not at all unusual for a novice to set a local variable in one method and expect the value to miraculously appear in another method, or to set an instance variable in one object and expect the value to appear in another.

Comment: (Show us how preDataWord is declared and initialized.)

Comment: thanks a lot all of you. i have edit my question.

Comment: Post more code!! :-) post: preData declaration (property? only instance variable?) and the syntesize (if exists and is not auto generated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the preDataWord ivar I'd first make sure it's declared and allocated properly:

```
//creates empty mutable array ...
NSMutableArray preDataWord = [NSMutableArray array];
```

And inside your for loop, add your NSNumber object to preDataWord like so:

```
[preDataWord addObject:num];
```